# Cocoa GUI - effects, polish

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, user-interface

I'm creating an in-car control screen (will be run from a Mac Mini) and am looking for some libraries or code samples for "effects". For example, I might want the name of the current track playing to fly in from the right. I might want screens to fade or slide up, etc.

I am aware that I can manually write these effects in Objective-C.

I am hoping there is a library like scriptaculous for JavaScript that allows me to easily manipulate an existing TextView, ImageView, etc.

A framework or otherwise is preferred. I'm working in native cocoa. I don't mind if the library costs $.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [**Core Image**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html) and [**Core Animation**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), both of which will allow you to add visual effects. Core Image, as its name implies, works with images only but can do fancy transitions. You can "fake" UI animations with it though by rendering a view to an image, swapping the image in in place or over the top of the view and then running a transition to another view.

Core Animation works directly with Cocoa Views and does have some transitions available. Both APIs (especially Core Animation) are fairly complex and have a learning curve.

Comment: I'm completely aware of those - but I'm asking about a ready made library. As I mentioned - something like scriptaculous for JavaScript. Say I have an NSImage already loaded into an NSImageView and I want it to "fly in from the left" or "fade in", or I want a NSTextField to scroll the contents. My question is about a ready made library that does this as simple as "[library flyInObject:myView fromDirection:kLEFT]". I am not interested in spending hours working my way through NSTransforms to get the proper effects - I'm assuming someone else has already done this.